# Java ScheduledExecutorService stopped some time after servlet initialization

Tags: java, servlets, scheduled-tasks

A function is implemented in my `Tomcat` server: basically a `ScheduledExecutorService` will be setup to run a task periodically upon the initialization of a `HttpServlet`. The code is like below:

```
@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    HttpsTool.setupUncheckedHttps();
    LOGGER.info("DeploymentInfoScheduler Initialized successfully....");
    System.out.println("DeploymentInfoScheduler Initialized successfully....");
    this.retrieveServiceDeploymentsInfo();
}

private void retrieveServiceDeploymentsInfo() {
    final Runnable deploymentsDataHandler = new DeploymentsDataHandler();
    final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle = deploymentsInfoRetrieverScheduler
            .scheduleAtFixedRate(deploymentsDataHandler, 0, 5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);


}
```

If the servlet is initialized successfully, the task will keep running every 5 seconds forever. In the `DeploymentsDataHandler`'s `run` method, A message is logged like below at the very beginning:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    LOGGER.info("Now begin a new round of refreshing deployment data...");
    this.doWorkFlow();
}
```

Correct me if I am wrong: no matter whether there is any exception unhandled in the `doWorkFlow` method, that message should always be logged every 5 minutes. But the fact is this scheduler runs well for some time and suddenly stops working, and even the message is stopped to be logged. Any possible explanation? How could I handle such an situation since I want to make sure this scheduler service is always running. Or is there any way to debug this issue?

I assume the following code will make sure the `Scheduler` will never stop executing even an exception occurs in the `doworkFlow`.

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try{
        LOGGER.info("Now begin a new round of refreshing deployment data...");
        this.doWorkFlow();
    }catch(Exception e){
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the last doWorkFlow definitely terminate? If not, no new task will start yet. You could add logging after doWorkFlow to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Correct me if I am wrong: no matter whether there is any exception unhandled in the doWorkFlow method, that message should always be logged every 5 minutes

No, since [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) explicitly says:

> If any execution of the task encounters an exception, subsequent executions are suppressed

Comment: Yes, unless the code throws an error and not an exception.